# Call the Click function by another click in jquery? is it possible

Tags: jquery

**JS:**

```
$('#button6').click(function () {

    $('#que1').hide();
    $('#que2').hide();
    $('#que3').hide();
    $('#que4').show();
    $('#que5').hide();
    $('#que6').hide();
    $('#que7').hide();
    $('#que8').hide();

    var line1 = $('.question3:checked').val();
    if (typeof line1 === "undefined") {
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("You Choosed", "nothing");
        msg.showAsync();
        $('#button6').click();
    }

});
```

It is possible? I want to return the same function if does not check any radio button.

But this is not working.

Comment: why are you using 7 hide methods? tou can do $('all the selectors you want divided by comma').hide() and you save 6 lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dangerous — if the condition is never satisfied, then you will be stuck in an infinite clicking loop.**

Otherwise, use: `$(selector).trigger("click")`.

---

Also, this line:

```
var line1 = $('.question3:checked').val();
if (typeof line1 === "undefined") { ... }
```

… can be simplified to:

```
if($('.question3').is('checked')) { .... }
```

Comment: Not working If i use this code ,the program has been terminated

Comment: This is because you will be creating an infinite loop - **your conditional logic needs to be evaluated**.

Comment: I agree with @Terry. It is not recommended.

Comment: $('#button6').trigger('click');
if i use this program termites at the run time

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I hate to repeat myself, but you are going to create an infinite loop. You need to rethinking (1) what you want to do and (2) what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam But if is not selected to begin with, then it will forever be triggering the click event without any way out of it.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I don't know what is your intention, but this will not work out. You need to find a better way to do this. What is the purpose of this feature, anyway?

Comment: I just put 8 questions in 1 page using jquery i show one question at a time others will be hidden at a time . if we enter the next button it will show next question like this I'll all question                                               now if not selected the radio button in the question the next question should not show.it should be hide state .are you clear ?? what i'm saying ..please help me dude

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Then let it be the user's decision to trigger the click event again. You don't have to do it for him.

Answer (score 0):

If your condition `if (typeof line1 === "undefined")` evaluates to `true`, then you are in infinite loop. Because you are clicking the same button again.

```
$('#button6').click(function () {
some condition{
    $( "#button6" ).trigger( "click" ); // Again triggering the same button click
  }
}
```

If the checkbox is not checked you can show the alert, but do not call the same button click again. What you can do is you can prompt the user to check again.

Comment: hmm ok I will do that

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is attempting to recurse... and is a terrible idea.
Don't hide que3 until you've verified it's been answered. Show que4 then too.
Consider the comments as well; that's how you could decorate question (e.g. add a red border).

```
var line1 = $('.question3:checked').val();
if (typeof line1 === "undefined") {
  // $("que3").addClass('error');
  return;
} else {
  // $("que3").removeClass('error');
  $('#que3').hide();
  $('#que4').show();
}
```